# Ruby on Rails has_many and form.select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When you update the post when I select multiple categories, as I pass additional prametrs my table relationships

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_categories
  has_many :categories, :through => :post_categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_categories
  has_many :posts, :through => :post_categories
end

# post_id,
# category_id, 
# lang  - string(2) example "en" or "ru"
class PostCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one    :post
  has_one    :category
end
```

And form

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
        <%= f.select :category_ids, options_for_select(Category.all.collect { |c| [c.title, c.id] },@post.categories.collect { |c| c.id }), {:include_hidden => false}, {:multiple => true, :class => 'form-select form-control-static', :style => 'width: 100%'} %>
</div>
```

Controller

```
# Сохранение нового поста
def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)
   # When create a post, I know how to pass parameter 3 to the bridge table, because I already have all the data in the links
   @post.post_categories.each do |с|
      с.lang = 'ru'
    end

   if @post.save
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    # How to pass parameters lang here, when updating the categories in the post?
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end

private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, {:category_ids => []})
    end
```

How to pass parameters lang here, when updating the categories in the post?

Comment: I suppose you should do with accepted_nested_attributes for post_categories so that you can include lang in post_params

Comment: How will the controller?

Comment: your lang attribute is in which table?